# Why does simply adding a field to an attribute table (in ArcMap) corrupt my shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

Just to get out in front of common advice- I am NOT using outside software like Excel to do this. It all takes place inside ArcMap.

I've been attempting to edit a shapefile full of point data. In particular I want to  add a new text field which will store a name for each of these points. In ArcMap I use "Add Data" to add in the shapefile. I open the shapefile's attribute table, use the options menu button, and hit "Add Field." Then I give it a short name, change type to "text", and that's that. I can then enter an edit session and give names to all these points, but in experimenting with this, I've learned that it doesn't matter whether I do this or not. If I save the edits, save the MXD, and close the file- the next time I open that MXD the shapefile will fail to load, and attempting to repair the data source or simply bring in the shapefile again with "Add Data" produces the error pop-up:

> Error opening feature class 
>  Number of shapes does not match the
> number of table records 
>  Number of shapes does not match the
> number of table records 
>  Class not registered.

Hit OK > A second, similar error pops up.

> Could not add the specified data object to the map. 
>  Number of
> shapes does not match the number of table records

After the fact, I've confirmed that the .dbf file looks correct to me in Excel. I don't understand why this is happening. I know there are shapefile repair utilities out there but I would at some point like to understand what is causing this issue because it is a very basic part of my workflow.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using? would advise not to open shapefile dbf in excel. There is most likely an issue between the geometry .shp and the index .shx check they are not read-only in windows.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new map (.mxd)? Sometimes odd things like that happen if the map gets corrupted. Also, make sure that no spaces are present in the map name.

Comment: I'm using 10.7. Neither are marked read-only. I only use excel to diagnose a problem file after I save a backup, never to edit or adjust a work file.

Comment: Try to open the original shapefile in arcmap then save it as a new shapefile . Then try to add your field to the new shapefile (exporting as a new shapefile is an easy way to repair a lightly corrupt shapefile)

Comment: @J.R This solved the issue! Thank you. I'm still confused as to why the original was corrupt but I suppose that answer will take more digging on my part. It was a shapefile freshly exported and re-exported from AutoCAD Map 3D so perhaps there is an issue somewhere in that process.

Comment: I got a very similar issue also using shp from DWG (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300342/using-field-calculator-on-shapefile-converted-from-dwg-in-arcgis-desktop) so this seem to be an issue with dwg to shp conversion, at last it's an easy fix...